# Access session in servlet applet communication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, applet

I have session problem in developing the servlet applet communication program.
I have login page in jsp after successful login of user i am guiding the user to a index.jsp page which has an applet. I have set a session variable in servlet before redirecting to index.jsp. In my applet i have to get the data stetted in session and some data from databse and properties file. my code is
//Servlet

```
if(action.equals("login")){
            uinfo = new UserInformation();

            String uid = request.getParameter("txt_UserName");
            String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd_PassWord");

            int i = uinfo.authenticateUser(uid, pwd);
            //System.out.println(i);
            if(i==1){
                session.setAttribute("uName", uid);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
else if(action.equals("applet")){
            try{

                output =  new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                uinfob= new UserInformationBean();

               Properties prop = new Properties();


                    try {
                           prop.load(new FileInputStream(path+"/connection.properties"));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

              uinfob.setHost(prop.getProperty("host"));
              uinfob.setIs_Active("Y");
              uinfob.setUid(session.getAttribute("uName").toString());


                 output.writeObject(uinfob);
                 output.flush();

                //output.close();

            }catch(IOException iox){
                iox.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                output.close();
            }
        }
```

In my applet

```
public void init() {

    try{

        String queryString="action=applet";

        URL codeBase = getCodeBase();
        URL servletURL = new URL(codeBase.getProtocol(), codeBase.getHost(), codeBase.getPort(), "/SwingBrowser1/UserServlet?"+queryString);

         servletConnection = servletURL.openConnection();
         servletConnection.setDoInput(true);
         servletConnection.setDoOutput(true);
         servletConnection.setUseCaches(false);
         servletConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
         servletConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
         getData();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
// TODO overwrite start(), stop() and destroy() methods

    public void getData()
    {
        try{
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(servletConnection.getInputStream());


           UserInformationBean uib =(UserInformationBean)input.readObject();



             System.out.println(uib.getHost()+"-------------"+uib.getIs_Active()+"-----------------"+uib.getUid());
            input.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It is getting java.io.EOFException error and i tested this with a sop in my else block of servlet. The attribute which i set before is returning null value.

Comment: Is your sessionid cookie sent with applet request?

Comment: no i am not sending any cookie in my index.jsp my code is like this     <applet code="com.garnet.malli.MyJApplet.class" archive="swing.jar, jfreechat.jar, kryonet.all.jar" />

Comment: I meant the SESSIONID cookie that app server is setting to responses of your aplication. I'd doublecheck if applet JVM picks it and uses that for it's requests as well (I think it mostly does it, but depends on applet JVM and its settings). Log all cookies recieved by server with each request and see if it is there.

Comment: Ok, and here is an answer that describes what to do if the sessionid is not between applet's cookies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956476/new-session-is-created-between-consecutive-servlet-request-from-an-applet-and-a

Comment: Thanks guys i have set that cookie it's working fine